# Can anyone help interpreting this equation?

Tags: mean, propensity-scores, integral

The following is a portion of text from the Heckman, Ichimura and Todd (1997) paper about propensity score matching in ReStud

---

The matching methods discussed in this paper focus on estimating an averaged version of
the mean effect of treatment on the treated
\begin{align}
M(S) = \frac{\int_S E(Y_1 - Y_0| X, D = 1)dF(X|D = 1)}{\int_S dF(X|D = 1)}
\end{align}

where $S$ is a subset of the support of $X$ given $D = 1$.

---

Can anyone offer an interpretation of this, especially the $dF(X|D = 1)$?

When I think of integrating to the get the expected value of a random variable (RV) I think of
$
E(X) = \int x f(x) dx
$
where $x$ is the realization of the RV, $f(x)$ is the probability of realization and $dx$ is the differential. Is $dF(X|D = 1)$ the differential? If so, why is there an $F$, which I always associate with a CDF, in there? That's the part I am really struggling with.

Comment: dF(x)=F'(x)dx=f(x)dx Where F is cdf and f is the pdf. That's a calculus shorthand. Does that make more sense now?

Comment: @KishKash I honestly never knew that. So, in this example, $dF(X|D = 1) = f(X|D = 1)dx$? That makes perfect sense to me now. So glad I asked the question, I could have wasted a whole night googling that! There is only one thing I'm not sure of. What are the values of the RV that we are integrating over, the '$x$' in my example? Is this included implicitly with the $\int_S$? Whatever values are in the subset of the support given $D$ = 1?

Comment: Yes. That's typically the assumption.